# What is the mathematical name of this kind of rotating ellipse?

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics

[image: Rotating ellipse]

Is there a general name in mathematics and/or physics applied to the kind of shape/motion shown in the attached picture? I need a word to refer to this shape/motion.

Comment: There are names for curves generated by specific processes, for example the curves generated by a pair of Spirograph gears. You might get a better answer if you could describe more clearly exactly where this curve comes from.

Comment: Are you talking about the [symbol for the atom?](https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/314/900/png-clipart-symbol-atomic-nucleus-science-violin-miscellaneous-chemical-element.png), or [this one without the electrons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Popular_culture_atom_symbol.svg)

Comment: It looks a bit like a [Rosetta orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_orbit).

Comment: [Apsidal precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsidal_precession)?

Comment: @DavidK In this case, the shape is generated by the motion of a pendulum.

Comment: With an initial velocity not collinear with the initial displacement, you can get a pendulum in an inertial frame to trace an ellipse. If you do this in a rotating frame you could get something like the picture. Since an ellipse can be constructed as a hypotrochoid I expect so can this figure. So indeed "hypotrochoid" (as in the answer below) seems to be what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Informally these are called 'spirograph' curves but there is also a mathematical name for these:  **[hypotrochoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotrochoid)**.  These are parametric curves $$f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$$ of the form
$$\begin{align}
x(\theta) &= (R - r) \cos \theta + d \cos \left(\frac{R - r}{R} \theta\right), \\
y(\theta) &= (R - r) \sin \theta - d \sin \left(\frac{R - r}{R} \theta\right), \\
\theta & \in \left[0, \frac{2 \pi \operatorname{lcm}(R,r)}{R}\right).
\end{align}$$
Here, $R$ and $r$ are radii, and $d$ is a distance parameter.  Your specific curve can be generated for the choices $R = 7$, $r = 3$, $d = 6$:

[image]

Many other choices are possible, each generating various interesting curves and patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Locus generated by means of rolling between two (or more) objects (without slipping) is called **roulette** and whereas locus by means of sliding between objects is called **glissette**.

In your sketch, the curve can be possibly generated by a [spirograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph).  You may say your curve is a kind of [hypotrochoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotrochoid) which is determined by three parameters.